# Logging with log4j in a mysql database using connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, log4j, connection-pooling

I have implemented a connection pool from JDBC to get and close connections for my data access objects in order to store and retrieve data from a mysql database with java.

I also wanted to store the main operations and exceptions in the database with a library called log4j through its appender called JDBCAppender.

before using the connection pool the logging of the events was fine since only one connection at a time was being utilized for operations. Now that the connections are simultaneously being grabbed from the pool and handed back to the pool, the logger doesnt seem to know how to get another connection once one connection (the first) is being closed.

How can I log into the database having a connection pool?

I have investigated in this myself and all I need to do is to override the getConnection() method in the JDBCAppender.java (which is in the apache log4j 1.2.16 library) ... but I have two questions.

Do i need to have my connection pool implementation class in the LOG4J 1.2.16 jar file?
Say if i get the connection from the pool, how do i recompile the LOG4J 1.2.16 Java files  into a jar file?

With what you have read so far i can provide with the my connection pool implementation and the JDBCAppender java class and we can take it from there ...

Comment: @duffymo, I do apologise for the caps lock I didn't mean to be rude sir. And I am trying hard thats why I seek for help, I know I am close and I am trying for making something to work :S ...

Comment: please refer to this link [http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html] in order to look at the recommendation for the solution to this problem ... Thank you

Comment: As for the link, are you saying that you've tried that link and failed to get the desired result?

Comment: @ Bekcs. If there is negative bounty schema, I would have given this question -50. Please work on duffymo's feedback. To start with I edited the question.

Comment: @duffymo I appreciate your feedback sir. I also appreciate @Flukey and @Jayan for their advices ... @duffymo, I have tried that link and not got the desired result sir, I only get the log in the database for operation that uses one connection ( only the first connection ) and the rest of the logging doesn`t happen ... I know that I need to override the getConnection() method of the JDBCAppender java class of log4j library in order to get the connection from my connection pool but I don't know whether I need to include the classes of Apache dbcp ( that I use for my pool ) inside the new log4j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to answer your specific question:  there is no need for your connection pool class to be in the Log4J `JAR`.  All you need is to have all classes and `JAR` files in your `CLASSPATH` when you run your code.  The `CLASSPATH` will pick up everything.  So this is not the cause of your problem.

I can't tell from your question vs. some later comments on it whether you are using your own connection pool, or a 3rd party one.  If the former, you should definitely switch to a 3rd party pool, like [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/), [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/), or [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/).  If the latter, then your issue is probably being caused by the way you configured the pool.  It definitely has nothing to do with the `JAR`s, which are all in your `CLASSPATH` and do not need to be combined or blended or anything like that.

I read the [javadoc for JDBCAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html) and noticed a few things. First, make sure you are overriding `closeConnection()`, not just `openConnection()`. Next, I noticed a warning that this class may be changed in the future, and also does not log exceptions.

For this reason, you may also want to use [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) instead of Log4J.  It is by the same author and represents newer technology.  Its [DBAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) seems to support logging of exceptions, and also allows you to plug in your `Connection` source, rather than overriding `getConnection()`.

Comment: thank you for your clarifications sir. I am using a connection pool implementation from the Apache DBCP. The javadoc for JDBCAppender reccomends to use JDBCAppender.java as a base class for my implementation of connections that are hired from a pool. Does this mean that I need to create another class that extends the JDBCApender but that calls MyConnPool.getConnection() and MyConnPool.close() instead of the getConnection() and close() of the JDCBAppender ones? In the log4j 1.2.16.jar in the log4j-1.2.16.jar\org\apache\log4j\jdbc I see a JDBCAppender.class, need I recompile? ..

Comment: JDBCAppender was written [with the intention that users subclass it](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/200111.mbox/%3C3BFB0278.1B7DFD4@pacbell.net%3E). You do not need to recompile the Log4J JAR.  Just make a subclass of JDBCAppender with the `getConnection()` and `closeConnection()` methods you described, and then specify that new class as your appender in your log4j config.  I also found [this document about configuring JDBCAppender](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm); everything in it should apply to your subclass as well.

Comment: What you say makes sense sir, but I do not understand how the config file will "understand" the new appender. My DBCP connection pool implementation is this [ConnectionProvider](http://pastebin.com/b1uvqFcx). My log4j.properties is [log4j.properties](http://pastebin.com/Pkc161f1). My issue is, how would a 'say' NewJDBCAppender.java with getConnection() and closeConnection() of the connection pool class work? ... What should I change in the log4j.properties file in order for the NEW JDBCAppender to work? ... Thank you sir...

Comment: Look at [the link I sent you before describing how to configure Log4J](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm). Change this line: `log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`, substituting the fully-qualified class name of your new JDBCAppender subclass for the `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender` value there.

Comment: Dear sparc_spread, ... could you please let me know what do you think of the overriden getConnection() method in my [NewJDBCAppender](http://pastebin.com/QxmaLdhY) ? ... If this seems fine to you, should I put this only in the source? ... Should I change the "log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender" into "log4j.appender.DB=com.ConnectionManager.ConnectionProvider" ? ... Please let me know what your opinion is to this ...

Comment: Dear Sir, Could you give me an opinion on my [NewJDBCAppender](http://pastebin.com/H4xasdH5) ? ... If you don`t see anything wrong with the new overriden methods getConnection() should I change the "log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender" into "log4j.appender.DB=com.ConnectionManager.NewJDBCAppender" ? ... Many thanks in advance for you help sir.

Comment: Overriding methods doesn't mean you need to copy the entire original source. You just provide implementations for the overridden methods. Also, you have no implementation for `closeConnection()` - you need to use that method to return the connection to the pool.  As for the config file change, yes, you are correct.